# xts - Delete rows based on certain criterias

Tags: r, xts

I need to delete xts rows based on certain criterias in column [code]. It is fine that by deleting there will be time-gaps in the xts time series.

**Question:** How do I solve step1/step3/step4.

---

The criterias are as following:

**Step-1: Value [3] in [code]:** If xts starts with [code] [3] delete that row.

**Step-2: Value [0] in [code]:** Delete the complete row.

**Step-3: Value [2] in [code]:** a) Keep only [2] that starts the xts, all lines above the first [2] should be removed.
b) Keep [2] that has a [3] above itself.

**Step-4: Value [3] in [code]:** Keep only [3] that has a [2] above itself.

My solution for step-2:

Finds and keeps, all [2] and [3], thus removing all [0]:

```
xts3 <- xts3[grep("[2]|[3]", xts3$code), ]
```

My R-file:

```
dates <- as.POSIXct( # Construct the dates to be used.
  c(
  "2013-07-24 09:01:00", 
  "2013-07-24 09:02:00", 
  "2013-07-24 09:03:00",
  "2013-07-24 09:04:00",
  "2013-07-24 09:05:00",
  "2013-07-24 09:06:00",
  "2013-07-24 09:07:00",
  "2013-07-24 09:08:00",
  "2013-07-24 09:09:00"
  )
  )

code <- c(3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3) # Criterias for delete/keep rows.

data <- data.frame(code) # Create a dataframe.

xts3 <- xts(x=data, order.by=dates) # Create xts based on dataframe.
```

The result of the R-file (prior to deleting rows based on criterias):

```
                    code
2013-07-24 09:01:00    3
2013-07-24 09:02:00    2
2013-07-24 09:03:00    0
2013-07-24 09:04:00    2
2013-07-24 09:05:00    2
2013-07-24 09:06:00    2
2013-07-24 09:07:00    3
2013-07-24 09:08:00    3
2013-07-24 09:09:00    3
```

Explanation: What should trigger delete of rows (based on criterias):

```
                    code
2013-07-24 09:01:00    3 # To be removed due to step-1.
2013-07-24 09:02:00    2 # To be kept due to step-3a.
2013-07-24 09:03:00    0 # To be removed due to step-2
2013-07-24 09:04:00    2 # To be removed due to not fulfilling step-3b
2013-07-24 09:05:00    2 # To be removed due to not fulfilling step-3b
2013-07-24 09:06:00    2 # To be removed due to not fulfilling step-3b
2013-07-24 09:07:00    3 # The kept due to step-4
2013-07-24 09:08:00    3 # To be removed due to not fulfilling step4.
2013-07-24 09:09:00    3 # To be removed due to not fulfilling step4.
```

Expected outcome after deleting rows has been done:

```
                    code
2013-07-24 09:02:00    2
2013-07-24 09:07:00    3
```

Comment: Interesting homework (guess), solution 2a you could do `xts3[which(xts3$code == 2)[1]:nrow(xts3), ]`.

Comment: @jay.sf It is actually not a homework. I am building a system that requires cleaning the xts.

Comment: Based on your example, please add an expected output. And do you need to use xts or can dplyr / data.table or something else be used as well? Also does rule 4 need to be implemented first or after rule 1-3 have been executed?

Comment: @phiver: I updated the question with expected outcome. I prefer to stay with xts but an alternative would be moving xts to dataframe thus loosing though the timestamp functionality from xts. I want to keep amount of loaded R package to its minimum. I re-ordered the steps so they make more sense in sequence.

Comment: @jay.sf I was asked to clarify the order of the steps, so your answer is solving step 3a.

Comment: Just realized, If 3a does its work it deletes all lines above the first [2]. it would make step-1 to not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 0, 2, and 3 as values you can use `diff` to get most of the rules in 1 go. Only those records are needed where the difference is 1 (2 above 3) or -1 (3 above 2). So the absolute value of `diff` will be what we need. And we need the first row where the value is 2. Those we combine to get the result xts3_filtered. 
    xts3_filtered <- c(xts3[first(which(xts3$code == 2))], xts3[abs(diff(xts3$code)) == 1])

```
                    code
2013-07-24 09:02:00    2
2013-07-24 09:02:00    2
2013-07-24 09:07:00    3
```

Now we have a duplicate row because both rules select the record where the first 2 occurs. So we remove any duplicates with the following code

```
xts3_filtered[!duplicated(index(xts3_filtered))]
                   code
2013-07-24 09:02:00    2
2013-07-24 09:07:00    3
```

Comment: - Phiver, The solution you provided work great on the minimized sample in the question. For some reason when running on my real R-file, the result is only showing the first found value [2], meaning only 1 line is visible. I will take my real file and strip it down both horizontal and vertical to run some tests and try to isolate what is the discrepancy  between the test-file and real-file.